# Swift 2.0: How to implement tableview controller with JSON API

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift2

I think this is a probably repeat question.

I am new to ios and and I am trying to learn so I don't expect response in actual codes. I still want to write them myself.

Here's what I have done so far: 
I wrote codes to make web api calls, authenticate and pull json data. 
I've figured out how to parse json data that I pulled from web. 
I have made tableview controller.

Challenge: How do I get the parsed Json data to tableview controller? 
Do I: 
- save it locally into like NSUSERDefaults variable? 
- save it to a global variable shared by controller and my model?
- at the end of the parsing json data do a return  so that it will be saved into viewController? 
- or none of the above and do ______________ (insert your answer)

What's the cleanest  way to do this? The table will initially have like 20 rows but as you pull down you will get more rows.

Comment: Look at the *Related* column. There are already a few answers or use the search function.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to save data on model class while parsing and store this class objects in an array and in cellforrowatindexpath get objects of model class from array and show data using these objects.